# CircleCi doesn't see my test

Tags: android, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

Why Circleci doesn't see my test?

I have test called MyAppTest.java. But when I run build on circleci it only shows the following results:

```
Your build ran 2 tests in testDebugUnitTest, testReleaseUnitTest with 0 failures
Slowest test: com.myapp.android.ExampleUnitTest addition_isCorrect (took 0.00 seconds).
```

Why it doesn't show result for MyAppTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this that configuration of my config.yml file was only for Unit tests. In the end I've found proper configuration for Instrumentation tests, but still faced error of not enough memory.